# Change Hibernate data type

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp

I am developing an application which makes use of Hibernate as was fully functional. However Yesterday I wanted and change a column (comment date) from the database from `Date` to `DateTime`.

I have a method which retrieves all the comments from the database and displays them in a table.  However since I changed the data type this is no longer working.

What should I do?

```
List<Comments> cmts = new CommentsHelper().getAllComments();

    out.println("<table class=\"tableC\"><tr><th class=\"name\" >User</th><th class=\"date\">Date</th><th class=\"comment\">Comment</th></tr>");

    for (Comments c : cmts)
    {
```

The error is in the enhanced for loop.

Here is the stacktrace:

```
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:470)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
root cause

java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to mediatek.Comments
    org.apache.jsp.comments_jsp._jspService(comments_jsp.java:269)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
```

Please also note I have tried to change the `commentDate` type from `Date` to `DateTime` in the `Comments` class (generated by Hibernate) but the error "cannot find symbol" is displayed.

Comment: your code is complete? i think u miss the code after "for (Comments c : cmts)"  fragment

Answer (score 0):

I don't think

```
new CommentsHelper().getAllComments();
```

is returning a

```
List<Comments>
```

It's returning a non-typed

```
List
```

You need an .addEntity(Comments.class); in your Hibernate code.

```
session.createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM Comments Order BY CommentDate")
    .addEntity(Comments.class).list();
```

Comment: 'public List<Comments> getAllComments()
    {
        List<Comments> comments = null;
        org.hibernate.Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        comments = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM Comments Order BY CommentDate").list();
        if(comments.size() > 0)
        {
            return comments;
        }
        return null;  
    }'

Comment: You need an .addEntity(Comments.class); in your Hibernate code. 

session.createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM Comments Order BY CommentDate").addEntity(Comments.class).list();

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime` is a jodatime class (right?) and hibernate won't be able to map a database timestamp to `DateTime` out of the box. The standard behaviour would be that hibernate serializes the object (`DateTime` is `Serializable`) and map it to a blob like structure on the database. That's probably not what you want.

But there is a quite easy solution: add [jadira usertypes](http://usertype.sourceforge.net/) to your project (and add some hibernate properties as explained in their documentation). Then you'll have a direct mapping form the database timestamps to your jodatime classes on the entities.